# How to change table of model dynamically in laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

It is known that after creating a new model, there is a function to change the table used by the model.

For example,

```
$example_model = new ExampleModel;
$example_model->setTable('myTable_'.$some_other_variable);
```

However, if I am finding record from table, is there a way to choose the table before querying the database?

i.e. something like this

```
$example_model = ExampleModel::setTable('myTable_'.$some_other_variable)->where('myColumn', $variable_to_be_compared)->get();
```

(Noticed that the following line is not correct. I will says setTable is not a static method)

I have some custom function in my model, so I would prefer not to use `DB::table('myTable_'.$some_other_variable)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the upstream `setTable()` method is that it returns nothing (void) so even you manage to call it you won't be able to chain it with other methods unless you override it.

```
// File: ExampleModel.php
/**
 * Set the table associated with the model.
 *
 * @param  string  $table
 * @return self
 */
public function setTable($table)
{
    $this->table = $table;
    return $this;
}
```

Then you can do something like this

```
$example_model = with(new ExampleModel)->setTable('myTable_'.$some_other_variable)->where('myColumn', $variable_to_be_compared)->get();
```

But since that solution involves writing the method, you could write instead a new static method for the task so you don't need to use helpers

```
/**
* Change the table associated with the model.
*
* @param  string  $table
* @param  array   $attributes
* @return self
*/
public static function changeTable($table, $attributes = [])
{
    $instance = new static($attributes);
    $instance->setTable($table);

    return $instance;
}
```

Which can be use

```
$example_model = ExampleModel::changeTable('myTable_'.$some_other_variable)->where('myColumn', $variable_to_be_compared)->get();
```